# JSP java.lang.NullPointerException When Moving Server

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am aware there a lot of threads about this error, but my situation is

- Site worked on one server (the old host)
- Site no longer works on new server (with TomCat installed and working)

We have a database up and running and I created a **conntest.do** file to make sure that we could connect to the database. However when we run the home page (i.e. no form data etc being posted) the following errors are created:

```
    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.ntech.realjosh.util.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:86)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.ntech.realjosh.util.DbUtil.dbStConClose(DbUtil.java:46)
    com.ntech.realjosh.util.RealjoshUtil.chkUserLock(RealjoshUtil.java:1378)
    com.ntech.realjosh.action.IndexAction.execute(IndexAction.java:25)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.ntech.realjosh.util.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:86)
```

The 'RealJosh' util is inherited and worked on the old server. The referenced **DBUtil** is the same except that the mysql access details have been updated.

The problem is as a hosting company we don't have a JSP Programmer in house but the client cannot get their site working on our server.

Any help you can be/give would be really gratefully received. If I need to post the content of any .java files let me know.
Thanks,

Martin

[edit] 
Here's the full DBUtil.java File:

```
public class DbUtil {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public void dbConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youngrob_database", "youngrob_user", "password");
            st = con.createStatement();
            Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Db Connected..........");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            st = '';
            con = '';
        }
    }

    public void dbClose() {
        try {
            if(getRs()!=null){
                getRs().close();
            }
            getSt().close();
            getCon().close();
            setRs(null);
            setSt(null);
            setCon(null);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void dbStConClose() {
        try {
         if(con!=null){
            getSt().close();
            getCon().close();
            //setSt(null);
            //setCon(null);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public void setCon(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public ResultSet getRs() {
        return rs;
    }

    public void setRs(ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(Statement st) {
        this.st = st;
    }
}
```

[edit 2] This is my conntest script which does work

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Connection with mysql database</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Connection status </h1>
<%
try {
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine name,
port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and
database name is usermaster. */
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youngrob_database";

// declare a connection by using Connection interface
Connection connection = null;

// Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters of
string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database. */
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "youngrob_user", "password");

// check weather connection is established or not by isClosed() method
if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<font size="+3" color="green"></b>
<%
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
</font>
<font size="+3" color="red"></b>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
}
%>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue seems to be that my conntest creates a valid mysql connection, but my DBUtil.java does not?

Comment: Share the `com.ntech.realjosh.util.DbUtil` sources, or at least the `dbStConClose` method source (and mark the line 46, where the NPE happens).

Comment: Question updated with the dbStConClose() function. Thanks!

Comment: Line 46 is `getSt.close()` within `dbStConClose()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing Statement `getSt().close();` by checking `null` value of `if(con!=null){`.
That's why it will throw NPE when Statement not initialized.

Your `dbStConClose()` method should be like:

```
public void dbStConClose() {
      try {
        if(getSt()!=null){
            getSt().close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

      try {
        if(getCon()!=null){
            getCon().close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
}
```

This code will prevent intermittent NPE (which depends on the initialization of Statement) and properly closing of DB resource.

**EDIT**: One more thing, there should be one **compilation error** in `dbConnection()` since you are assigning blank charecter to the Statement and Connection references, in case of exception, which is wrong. If you are not able to get the connection then code should throw Exception (better SQLException) stating failed to get connection. Initializing with null or empty value is not a solution in case of Database, rest is depend on yours choice.

```
public void dbConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youngrob_database", "youngrob_user", "password");
        st = con.createStatement();
        Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Db Connected..........");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        // st = '';
        // con = '';
        // throw new SQLException("Failed to get DB Connection");

        // if you can not throw checked exception then          
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get DB Connection");          
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies for abandoning this thread - had a tricky few months health-wise, but your reply was the most useful there, so I will mark it as such. Being asked to update JSP as their web host while never having coded JSP before was... challenging! Your help was appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tomcat lib folder and compare both location. My guess is that existing one has a jdbc driver jar and latest one doesn't.

Comment: If that were true then my 'conntest' script should also fail, which it doesn't and I can create a valid mysql connection via JSBC in my conntest script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to edit the `.class` file and recompile it with the correct connection details. Not being a Java/JSP coder I didn't realise this.

But by doing this my NullPointerException has gone away. Totally new situation now, but I'm moving forward. Thanks for your help, both!